# how can I set single attribute for multiple input with multiple condition?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel-8

I use Add More button for adding new row with elements. The problem is very first time my all conditions for dependency dropdown and other input fields are working fine. But when I add new elements click on Add button then my dependency dropdown and other conditions are not working in jQuery. How can I make it working? I am using Laravel-8.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d9zX.png)

My Html Code:

```
<div class="row" id="add_item_detail_1">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group" style="position: relative">
            <label class="col-form-label" for="serviceCategory">Service Category</label>
            <select name="serviceCategory[]" id="serviceCategory"
                class="form-control">
                <option value="0" selected disabled>--- Select Service Category ---
                </option>
                @foreach ($service_category as $category)
                    <option value="{{ $category->id }}">
                        {{ $category->name }}
                    </option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-form-label" for="serviceItem">Select Item</label>
            <select name="serviceItem[]" id="serviceItem" class="form-control">
                <option value="0" selected disabled>--- Select Item ---</option>
                @foreach ($service_items as $item)
                    <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            <img id="serviceloader" src="{{ asset('admin/img') }}/loader.gif"
                alt="Loading..." />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-form-label" for="price">Price/Item</label>
            <input type="text" id="price" name="price[]" value="" placeholder="Price"
                class="form-control" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-form-label" for="product_qty">Qty</label>
            <input type="number" id="product_qty" name="product_qty[]" min="0" value=""
                placeholder="0" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-form-label" for="totalPrice">Total Price</label>
            <input type="text" id="totalPrice" name="totalPrice[]" value=""
                placeholder="T.Price" class="form-control" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-form-label" for="vendorArea">Vendor Area</label>
            <select class="form-control m-b" name="vendorArea[]" id="vendorArea">
                <option value="0" selected disabled>--- Select Vendor Area ---</option>
                @foreach ($areas as $venArea)
                    <option value="{{ $venArea->id }}">{{ $venArea->area_name }}
                    </option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-form-label" for="vendorName">Vendor Name</label>
            <select class="form-control m-b large-bootstrap-select" name="vendorName[]"
                id="vendorName">
                <option value="0" selected disabled>--- Select Vendor ---</option>
                @foreach ($vendors as $vendor)
                    <option value="{{ $vendor->id }}">{{ $vendor->ven_name }};
                        Phone: {{ $vendor->ven_phone }} </option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    {{-- <input type="hidden" name="id" value=""> --}}
    <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-form-label text-white btn-label-order-add-more"
                for="price">AM</label>
            <button type="submit" id="btn-add-more-items"
                class="btn btn-info btn-outline btn-order-add-more"
                onclick="add_more_item()"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    
    var serviceLoader = $('#serviceloader'),
        serviceCategory = $('#serviceCategory'),
        serviceItem = $("#serviceItem"),
        vendorArea = $('#vendorArea'),
        vendorName = $('#vendorName'),
        itemPrice = $('#price');

    serviceLoader.hide();
    serviceItem.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    vendorName.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    serviceCategory.change(function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        // alert(id);
        if (id) {
            serviceLoader.show();
            serviceItem.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $.ajax({
                url: "/getServiceItem/" + id,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    // console.log(response);

                    let sItem = '<option value="0">---Select Item---</option>';

                    response.forEach(function(row) {
                        sItem += '<option value="' + row.id + '">' + row.name +
                            '</option>';
                    });

                    $('#serviceItem').removeAttr("disabled");
                    $('#serviceItem').html(sItem);
                    serviceLoader.hide();

                }
            });
        }
    }); //end select Items

    serviceItem.change(function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        // alert(id);
        if (id) {

            $.ajax({
                url: "/getItemPriceByID/" + id,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    itemPrice.val(response[0].price);
                    $('#product_qty').val('');
                    $('#totalPrice').val('');
                }
            });
        }

    }); //end service Items

    $("#product_qty").keyup(function() {
        var itemPrice = $('#price').val();
        var itemQty = $('#product_qty').val();
        var totalPrice = itemPrice * itemQty;
        $('#totalPrice').val(totalPrice);
    }); //end price calculation

    vendorArea.change(function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        // alert(id);
        if (id) {
            vendorName.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $.ajax({
                url: "/getVendorByID/" + id,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) {
                    // console.log(response);
                    let sVendor = '<option value="0">---Select Vendor---</option>';

                    response.forEach(function(row) {
                        sVendor += '<option value="' + row.id + '">' + row
                            .ven_name + ',' + row.ven_phone +
                            '</option>';
                    });

                    $('#vendorName').removeAttr("disabled");
                    $('#vendorName').html(sVendor);
                }
            });
        }
    }); //end select Vendor Name

});
```

Comment: You must re-declare you listener function after element append to DOM in your `add_more_item()` function

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suspect your selectors are too specific. Please look at `.on()` as well. This way you can assign a callback to items that have not yet been added.